# Bitwig doesn't have ties in the imported Midi file

Tags: software, midi, daw, guitar-pro, bitwig

When I create a MIDI file in Guitar Pro 6, and load it into Bitwig, everything is fine, except for the ties. For instance, I create this track on Guitar Pro:

[image]

Export it as MIDI and load it onto Bitwig. This is what I get:

[image]

[image]

Instead of the tie, there is nothing there, and of course there is no sound in that part.

In this simple example I can easily drag the line and fix the problem, but when I have a long piece, with many ties, it can get really tiresome. Is there any way I can fix this?

Also, is the problem generated from Guitar Pro, when the file is created, or is there something wrong with the way Bitwig loads the file?

Comment: I would think the problem is in guitar pro as there is no information on ties in midi, just absolute midi clock values that can be read from standard notation.

Comment: @Dom so it's some kind of Guitar Pro bug?

Comment: you'll get better help from the guitar pro forum where they support the product.

Comment: @Shevliaskovic yes as if it's bitwig's problem it has nothing to do with ties.

Answer (score 1):

The only way that I found to solve this is to export the file to .gp5 file extension and open it in guitar pro 5, then export midi from there.

Hope this solution helps.

Answer (score 1):

I would anticipate this to be a bug in Guitar Pro, as this piece of software isn't known for having the best export routines...

If you don't wanna wait, until Arobas Music fixed that, try the following in the meantime: Export a MusicXML file from Guitar Pro. Install MuseScore (free), open file there and try to export a MIDI file from MuseScore.

Answer (score 0):

pick some other midi viewer than bitwig and see if it has the same problem.  if so, guitar pro is at fault.  if not, bitwig is at fault.  i'd suspect guitar pro off the top of my head.  they probably have a much better support forum anyway.

then go to whichever forum (which probably would have been a good idea to do in the first place) and pray that they'll prioritize your fix.

Comment: We've had many questions pertaining music software just -> [here](http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software)

Comment: Why is it downvoted? His answer is totally the correct way to figure out the problem.

Comment: This answer is the correct way to diagnose the problem. Sevliaskovic: do what this answer says, and then you will know if it's Bitwig's or Guitar Pro's fault.

Answer (score 0):

MIDI doesn't deal with ties, clefs, articulation symbols, any of that stuff. Ties are a part of written music notation. MIDI is a digital interface for communicating with musical instruments, whereas musical notation is for communicating to human musicians. Does your guitar have a "tie" button?

In your screenshot you have two *written notes* that are tied together, but they are used for describing a single *sounding note*. Most probably the issue should be corrected on the exporting program's side.